# Is there an RSS feed that shows the latest security patches released for Drupal core

Tags: drupal

I am seeking an RSS feed or something similar that I can read with a script to detect when new security patches are released for Drupal core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feed for Drupal core security: **http://drupal.org/security/rss.xml**

You can find more information in **[this article](https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2009-03-18/new-pages-and-rss-feeds-for)**.